# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKUserLocation annotationType]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, mapkit

i am receiving this error when trying to add user location. I have a table view and when i try to scroll, i receive this error. I'm very new to xcode.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MKUserLocation annotationType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x803f090'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are lots of reasons that can cause this error. Please, include some source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKUserLocation does not have an annotationType method. You're sending MKUserLocation a message that it does not know how to handle.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  My program does have an "annotationType" method, which I step through in the debugger, but as soon as it exits I receive the NSInvalidArgument.  As far as I can tell everything is wired up properly.  Do you have any suggestions in terms of how I could determine why "MKUserLocation" is receiving a message it does not know how to handle and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am encountered this before, it is normally because of simple & not obvious type of mistake i.e format wrong - didn't call a function based on the unexpected format, type wrong.

I used:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ABC:) ....name:@"UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

The "ABC" function, I declared not based on the expected function format.

Instead of:

```
- (void) ABC:(NSNotification *)notification
```

I used:

```
- (NSString *)DDD
```